# Sending double data serially AVR

Tags: serial-port, avr

I want to send the reading of temperature sensors serially from an Atmenga32 to another Atmega32.
But since serial data transmission is only 8-bits,how do i send the data by dividing it into blocks of 8 bits.And how do I receive the same.
For eg: if the ADC value is 32.78

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ADC in AVR is in unsigned 10-bit form, not a double. And the ADC can be read as two separate bytes, ADCL and ADCH. ADCL must be read first.

If you want to send some other `uint16_t val`  use

```
uint8_t lo = (uint8_t)val;
uint8_t hi = (uint8_t)(val >> 8);
```

`double` and `float` are both 4 bytes long. If you want to send a `double dval` use this trick

```
uint32_t val32 = * (uint32_t *) &dval;
```

(Create a pointer to the dval with the address operator `&`. Cast that pointer to a pointer to a `uint32_t`, which is a variable taking up the same number of bytes. Then dereference the pointer to get the value, which goes into val32.

This is not the same as simply casting the dval to a uint32_t. That would truncate the number.)

Send `val32` in 4 pieces by shifting as above. Recover by shifting and `|`, then use a similar pointer trick to turn the result back into a double.

Comment: Thanks a lot,could you please explain how this statement works:         uint32_t val32 = * (uint32_t *) &dval;

Comment: @UncleO: It is probably cleaner casting &dval to uint8_t* like `uint8_t* pData = (uint8_t*)&dval;` and using pData to send the double.